# dragging a popup distance between finger touch and popup movement

Tags: android

```
public class PopupDragUtility implements OnTouchListener {

ReaderLaunchActivity readerAct;
PopupWindow targetWindow;
private float dX = 0;
private float dY = 0;

public PopupDragUtility(ReaderLaunchActivity readerAct, PopupWindow targetWindow) {
    super();
    this.readerAct = readerAct;
    this.targetWindow = targetWindow;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View p_v, MotionEvent p_event) {
    switch (p_event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        dX = p_event.getRawX();
        dY = p_event.getRawY();
        break;
    }
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

        if (readerAct.deviceOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            float newX = p_event.getRawX() - 390;
            float newY = p_event.getRawY();

            System.out.println("newX    " + newX);
            System.out.println("newY   " + newY);

            if (newX > -390 && newY > 75 && (newX + targetWindow.getWidth()) < readerAct.readerLayout.getWidth()
                    && (newY + targetWindow.getHeight()) < readerAct.readerLayout.getHeight()) {

                targetWindow.update((int) newX, (int) newY, -1, -1, true);

            }

        } else {
            float newX = p_event.getRawX() - 140;
            float newY = p_event.getRawY();

            System.out.println("newX    " + newX);
            System.out.println("newY   " + newY);

            if (newX > -140 && newY > 75 && (newX + targetWindow.getWidth()) < readerAct.readerLayout.getWidth()
                    && (newY + targetWindow.getHeight()) < readerAct.readerLayout.getHeight()) {

                targetWindow.update((int) newX, (int) newY, -1, -1, true);

            }
        }

        break;
    }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am trying to drag a rectangular shaped icon within the screen bounds.
    But I am facing a problem where there is a distance between my finger touch
    and the pop up movement.I have temporary resolved this issue with the help 
    of some constants.But Can anyone suggest a solution without constants.
 Here target window is the reference of the popup and reader layout is the
    reference of the entire screen.

Comment: You will need X and Y constants to hold the offset values. There's no way to do it without, unless you're okay with the window "snapping" to position.

Comment: But why is there an offset value.why is the image not moving on the touch of my fingers.I think while using the popup window.update the popup is not taking the x cordinate as the leftmost position of image.

Comment: i have placed constants for a 10 inch device.Now I want the code running for a 7 inch device and 5 inch phone.Using constants wont help a bit.Can anyone suggest a better answer without using constants?

Comment: "But I am facing a problem" what problem is it?

Comment: @pskink there is a distance between my finger touch position and the movement of the image.So while my finger touch goes to the extreme left corner of the screen ,there is an offset between the image and movement.

Comment: make sure that newX and newY are always >= 0, also they should not be > screen size minus dragged object size

Comment: @pskink that's the main problem i am already checking that condition in the if statement as I want the drag object to remain in bounds.But its not working. Theres an offset between touch position and image.

Comment: no,  you are checking "if (newX > -390 "

Comment: @pskink U DINT READ MY QUESTION PROPERLY.i AM SUBTRACTING 390 BECAUSE OF THE DIFFERENCE IN MOTION OF THUMB AND IMAGE MOVEMENT. iTS WORKING THIS WAY,BUT i DONT WANT TO USE CONSTANTS IN MY CODE.

Comment: i was just about to give you complete working code, but it seems that "YOU KNOW BETTER WHATS WRONG IN YOUR CODE", in such case i will not argue with you

Comment: @pskink. Chiil dude.!! Relax..I know whats wrong in my code.But i don't know how to correct it.I have tried everywhere and cant find an optimal solution,Thats's why I asked this question.

Comment: no,  you seem not to know what's wrong as you are passing negative x and y positions to update() method

Comment: @pskink ya thats what I want to improve.While passing negative values to update button code seems to be working fine.I dont know how but its working.So can you implement and suggest me a better generic method that could work for all devices.

Comment: i already told you what's wrong: "make sure that newX and newY are always >= 0, also they should not be > screen size minus dragged object size"

Comment: @pskink dude I tried that but the results are not showing up.Can you think of something else?

Comment: so it seems you did it wing way,  the solution i gave you is the right one

Comment: @pskink if u are so confident of your answer why not you try it in your code.and reply if you are getting the answers.

Comment: yes i tried that in my vode,  otherwise i wouldn't waste your time

Comment: @pskink can u give that copy of that code.Let me also check and verify it

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int touchX = (int) event.getX();
    int touchY = (int) event.getY();
    ObjectAnimator animation1, animation2;
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        animation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(findViewById(R.id.imgLauncher),
                "y", touchY);
        animation1.setDuration(2000);
        animation1.start();

        animation2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(findViewById(R.id.imgLauncher),
                "x", touchX);
        animation2.setDuration(2000);
        animation2.start();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        animation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(findViewById(R.id.imgLauncher),
                "y", touchY);
        animation1.setDuration(2000);
        animation1.start();

        animation2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(findViewById(R.id.imgLauncher),
                "x", touchX);
        animation2.setDuration(2000);
        animation2.start();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        animation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(findViewById(R.id.imgLauncher),
                "y", touchY);
        animation1.setDuration(2000);
        animation1.start();

        animation2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(findViewById(R.id.imgLauncher),
                "x", touchX);
        animation2.setDuration(2000);
        animation2.start();
        break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Its using the objectAnimator class but i want to make the image drag.

Comment: and while using getX() instead of getRawX() the image tends to fliker

Comment: check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006775/how-to-drag-images-around-the-screen)